# create a new branch from anotrher one created by another user

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitlab

I want to create a new branch with git (using Gitlab) from another branch created by another user, I habe tried :

```
  git checkout -b myBranch origin/TheOtherBranch
```

but he doesn't recognize the other branch since it is created by another user, inpite I can see it in my gitlab account,

I have also tried to merge with that branch but in vain.

PS: merging with master isn't the solution

Comment: Do `git fetch` first

Comment: git fetch thOtherBranch : he doesn't recognize the other branch (error : does not appear to be a git repository)

Comment: Just `git fetch`, without arguments. This will synchronize your local repo with your gitlab account. `origin/TheOtherBranch` should then exist in your local repo

Answer (score 2):

```
git fetch
```

This will download all new commits and their respective branches and tags from the remote `origin` by default.

```
git checkout -b myBranch origin/TheOtherBranch
```

This will now know about `origin/TheOtherBranch` and create your local `myBranch` to point at that commit.

If it does not work:

```
git branch -a | grep /origin/
```

Shows all branches from that remote, maybe it's a typing/spelling error...